# Is VLC 2.2 available for elementary OS Freya?

Tags: release-freya, vlc

[image]

Installing in this way with `apturl` what I get is VLC. 2.1.6

[image]

But this is maybe a larger Ubuntu issue?

I know a PPA that can work (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`) - from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/565759/47206).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you asking how to get the latest version or if it will be available in the official repos or something else?

Comment: @DanielForé - I was just wandering if it's "as expected". I know of a PPA  for VLC 2.2 in  ubuntu 14.04 and Freya. (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media&&sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get install vlc`)

Comment: @DanielForé - the new edited title of the question has the answer "yes", that is: yes, VLC 2.2 IS available for Freya, only not from the daily stable PPA. So, I made an edit to the answer with the other PPA and  links to .deb files. I don't have enough reputation here yet to avoid peer review :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

elementary OS Freya (0.3) is based on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and the latest available version of VLC for this version of Ubuntu is 2.1.x (so 2.1.6).

This PPA  provides the latest version though (at least for the moment):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

To have the `.deb` file, look on [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&keywords=vlc) or [http://pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/download/vlc)

Comment: The latest possible in the official ppa. You can build the latest version if you want to or use an other unofficial ppa.

Comment: @cipricus Done, and i'm not a native Enligh speaker either